# Strange browser issue regarding hyperlink colours (Firefox vs. Safari on an iMac)

Tags: css, firefox, browser, safari, hyperlink

If you wouldn't mind heading over to [my site](http://blog.twostepmedia.co.uk/) and viewing it in Safari on a Mac and Firefox on a Mac, the hyperlink colours change between the usual blue in FF and purple in Safari. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is actually no difference between how FF and Safari handles your site; if you visit/click on the links in both browsers you will notice that the color will change in each browser to a purple indicating you have visited the site. This is simply a default CSS property.

If you do not like this property, add this to your CSS:

```
a:visited {color:blue;}
```

This change will set the link to blue even after someone visits the link.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

One of the CSS files from your theme is setting the link colour to blue. As Eric says, you can change this to any colour you like (or remove it if you want the default).

http://blog.twostepmedia.co.uk/wp-content/themes/thematic/library/styles/default.css

`a:link {
    color:#004B91;
}`

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your CSS and use the color of your choice

```
a:link {color:orange;}

a:visited {color:blue;}

a:hover {color:red;}  

a:active {color:green;}
```